# Magnetic Shielding?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

Can magnetic fields be "blocked"?
For example, in the game, TitanFall, a robot stop bullets with ( presumably ) a magnetic shield.

I wish to calculate the magnetic force required to stop a bullet within a few microseconds.  But the problem I have is that my entire electronic system or the vehicle ( most likely even a building ) will be subjected to massive fields most likely destroying it as well.

Does any know of a way to "block" or divert the field around my vehicle? Is it even possible?
My knowledge in magnetic fields are quite limited at this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21138/ or http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62151/

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus if I'm interpreting the question right, neither of those are duplicates.  The question isn't about shielding magnetism but rather using magnetism as a shield.  And the answer is "no" for neutral, non-ferrous projectiles like copper or lead bullets.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: His wording seemed to imply that the force calculation was something separate, since the only sentences with question marks were "Can magnetic fields be "blocked"?" "Does any know of a way to "block" or divert the field around my vehicle?" and "Is it even possible?".

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus yeah it's unclear what's being asked.

Comment: I see the error I made in my question.  It was 3am in the morning for me, my bad.  Basically, can bullets be stopped by a magnetic field?  And if so, can I protect my equipment from the magnetic field that I generated, as to not destroy my hardware?

Answer (score 1):

If you google "magnetic shielding" you will find plenty about commercially available materials for this purpose.

Do keep in mind that force fields in video games are science fiction, not physics. There is no reason to presume that force fields are magnetic fields, or that magnetic fields are a reasonable way to stop bullets, or that all bullets will even respond to magnetic forces.

Comment: OK, fair. But, assuming the bullet can react to magnetic forces.  Can a magnetic field be strong enough to stop a bullet within a small amount of time?

Comment: Certainly. But a magnetic field is more likely to be used to launch bullets. Look up "railgun".

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, and have personally built a small one my self.  This question is merely to resolve a debate me and a few friends had.  I thought someone here might be able to supply me with an answer or a starting point for research perhaps, but it has turned into a completely off topic discussion about whether or not a stated the question clearly.