# Is it possible to shield a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Is it actually possible to shield a magnetic field? They teach us at school that magnetic fields are generated by electricity running through the wires (that's how electromagnets work). On the other hand there are permanent magnets which just get magnetized and then keep the magnetic field. Is it possible to shield those?

Btw, I don't want to destroy the field totally, but rather temporary "disable".

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103675/2451 and links therein. See also [Meissner effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect).

Comment: @Alfred Centauri the link is broken...

Comment: @user2677034, thanks, and I deleted. I can't find it on The Wayback Machine etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes, at least for some values of "jam".

The classic example along these lines was the measures/countermeasures struggle between Britain and Germany using magnetic mines during WWII. [These mines](https://medium.com/war-is-boring/how-britain-beat-germanys-wwii-magnetic-sea-mines-bfec5558704c#.w8h611jov) responded to the magnetic field produced by steel-hulled ships passing overhead. The solution was to add a belt of electric cable around the ships' hulls, and adjusting a current through the cable to produce a magnetic field which cancelled the intrinsic field from the hull. The approach was generally successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the magnetic field by turning off the current. (Eg. Spin echo or Rabi oscillation experiments in NV center in diamond) 
For permanent magnet, I think you can only block the field physically.