# Is there any material that a magnetic field cannot penetrate?

Tags: electromagnetism, chemical-compounds

Is there any way to build an enclosure that protects its contents from magnetic fields more effectively than simply keeping sources of magnetic fields away by the same distance the box would?

Comment: Yes, a box made from mu-metal does a good job for magnetic shielding.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62151/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21138/